# Angular Shallow unit test InvalidPipeArgument with Async pipe

Tags: typescript, jasmine, angular11

I am trying to write a simple test in angular with Shallow render. I am using Async pipe in the html template to render the observable. I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '() => this.referenceDataService.getRoutes() 
    .pipe(Object(rxjs_operators__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__["map"])((routes) => {​​​ debugger; return routes || []; }​​​))' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

Component:

```
routes$: Observable<RouteModel[]>;
   routes$ = () => this.referenceDataService.getRoutes()
    .pipe(map((routes: RouteModel[]) => {
        debugger;
        return routes || [];
    }));
```

test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    routes = [
        { routeId: 1, prefix:'/test1', route:'/test1' }, 
        { routeId: 2, prefix:'/test2', route:'/test2' }
    ]

    dataServiceMock = {
        getRoutes: () => of(routes)
    };

    shallowComponent = new Shallow(RouteComponent, AppModule)
    .provideMock([
        { provide: ReferenceDataService, useValue: dataServiceMock}
    ])
    .dontMock([FormBuilder]);
});

it('should create',  async () => {
    const { instance } = await shallowComponent.render();
    expect(instance).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Can anyone please help me what the issue is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the code work when you do `npm start`?

The issue is the `()`, the `async` pipe can only bind to an `Observable` and not a function that returns an `Observable` unless if you call that function in the HTML which is not recommended because it will slow down the application because the function will be called every time change detection runs.

Try this:

```
// get rid of the () =>
routes$ = this.referenceDataService.getRoutes()
    .pipe(map((routes: RouteModel[]) => {
        debugger;
        return routes || [];
    }));
```